# Faraday timeout

Tags: ruby

I've searched the docs and other places online and cannot seem to come up with the proper way to set the timeout option for Faraday. Anyone have the answer?

I've tried:

```
  conn = FaradayStack.build(url)
  conn.headers[:user_agent]   = AppConfig.user_agent
  # conn.options[:timeout]      = 20
  # conn.options[:open_timeout] = 20
  response = conn.get do |req|
    req.options = {
      :timeout      => 20,
      :open_timeout => 20
    }
  end
  response.body
```

Nothing seems to be working. BTW, I'm using the Typhoeus adapter if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well it seems I figured it out. If I pass the timeout option into the initializer, it seems to work:

```
  options = {
    :timeout      => 20,
    :open_timeout => 20
  }
  conn = FaradayStack.build(url, options)
  conn.headers[:user_agent] = AppConfig.user_agent
  conn.get.body
```

Comment: A little more up to date answer, https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/issues/417

Answer (score 11):

The [Faraday README](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/#usage) currently contains this example using a block style:

```
conn.get do |req|
  req.url '/search'
  req.options[:timeout] = 5           # open/read timeout in seconds
  req.options[:open_timeout] = 2      # connection open timeout in seconds
end
```

If this doesn't work for you, perhaps you should file a ticket over on Github.

Comment: The original question seems to be asking about the general timeout, rather than per-request timeouts which the above refers to.